# rails recursive method problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a problem trying to get a recursive method to work in rails/ruby.  The purpose is to find all ancestor categories of a given category based on the parent_id.  The current method does return the right ancestor categories, but it is nesting the array.  I think this is because I'm initializing the category_ancestors array, and then it is getting reinitialized as the method recurses through itself.  I'm trying to figure out how to change this so that I get a single level array with the category attributes rather than how it is outputting the data now.

```
def self.get_ancestors(category)

category_ancestors = []   # <-- this seems to be the problem

category_ancestors << category.attributes

if category.has_parent?
  category.get_parent.each do |parent_category|
    category_ancestors << get_ancestors(parent_category)
  end
end

category_ancestors.reverse

end
```

This returns something like which is nesting the arrays (but I need them all at the same level):

```
--- 
  - - - name: Category 1
    id: 1
    created_at: 2011-09-04 22:56:43.198413 Z
    updated_at: 2011-09-07 00:14:09.934813 Z
    parent:id 

 - name: Category 2
   id: 2
   created_at: 2011-09-04 22:56:43.198413 Z
   updated_at: 2011-09-07 00:14:09.934813 Z
   parent:id: 1

- name: Category 3
  id: 3
  created_at: 2011-09-04 22:56:43.198413 Z
  updated_at: 2011-09-07 00:14:09.934813 Z
  parent:id: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a non-recursive version that does the same thing

```
class Category
  def ancestors
    result = []
    c = self
    while c.parent
      result.unshift(c.parent)
      c = c.parent
    end
    result
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a flat array, you should use concat() to join the elements into a single array instead of ending up with an array of arrays.

```
  def self.get_ancestors(category)

    category_ancestors = []   # <-- this seems to be the problem

    category_ancestors << category.attributes

    if category.has_parent?
      category.get_parent.each do |parent_category|
        category_ancestors.concat(get_ancestors(parent_category))
      end
    end

    category_ancestors.reverse

  end
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I now see that I should have been using concat to keep things in a single array.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
category_ancestors += get_ancestors(parent_category)
```